# Passing values to wordpress shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php while (have_rows('home_playlist', 'option')): the_row();
$track = get_sub_field('home_track'); ?>
echo $track;
```

Here echo generate some selective IDs 2,4,7,10,12 (mp3 songs title) from wp panel. And I need to show the title on the player. How do i pass the value of $track into the 'ids'....

Comment: need to pass the data of $track into ids <?php mp3j_put( '[popout ids="" autoplay="y"]' ); ?>

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$tracks=array();
while (have_rows('home_playlist', 'option')): the_row();
    $tracks[] = get_sub_field('home_track'); ?>
$list= implode(',',$tracks);
echo $list;
mp3j_put( '[popout ids="'.$list.'" autoplay="y"]' ); ?>
```

Comment: thanks @ Jehy. But its getting the last ID. that means only loaded 12.

Comment: hallo, it is not working. echo show the ID of the content. But when I tried to use in ids="'.$list.'" then the popup is not working.